# Perl and IRC: Periodically send a message to a channel

Tags: perl, irc, poe

I'm making a Perl IRC bot and I want to send a message periodically to a channel. I'm using [POE::Component::IRC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE-Component-IRC/lib/POE/Component/IRC.pm), but as far as I can see, there is no method or event handling this.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't that what the `privmsg` command (http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE-Component-IRC/lib/POE/Component/IRC.pm#privmsg) does? (Despite the "priv" in its name, it's documented as sending "a public or private message".)

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be called within one of the event handlers.. like irc_public (which loads when creating a POE session).

Comment: Are you saying you can't find a POE method of creating a timer?

Comment: Lasse, I have created a powerful solution but it's too much to put here. Would you like me to put it on pastie or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use POE::Kernel's `delay` routine to act like a one-time timer calling itself over and over.

Basically, you have an event handler named `my_event`. Within `my_event`, you send the PRIVMSG to the channel. You then call this same event handler `my_event` using the `delay` routine inherited through POE.

See: *[POE: Cookbook - Recurring Alarms](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/Recurring_Alarms)*